# Is it possible in dplyr to manipulate the input data set?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am applying multiple filter and select operations on a dataframe with dplyr. Is it possible to directly change the data in the input object?

So I want to achieve something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
filter(mpg>20) %>%
select(cyl) <- mtcars %>%
filter(mpg>20) %>%
transmute(cyl=8)
```

Obviously, this results in an error.

In base R it would look like this:

```
mtcars[which(mtcars$mpg>20),"cyl"] <- 8
mtcars
```

Comment: You mean, like `mtcars <- mtcars %>% filter...` ? Your error is obviously caused by the arrow in the middle of your pipeline.

Comment: Be aware that if you modify the data set like that (with the same name) you will have to work at it to get the original data reloaded.   Better to use a temporary name.

Comment: If I would run: mtcars <- mtcars %>%
 filter(mpg>20) %>%
 transmute(cyl=8)
 mtcars then Only the Cylinders are returned. I would like to get the whole  dataframe with the changed cylinders.

Comment: This is because you want `mutate`, not `transmute`. And beware of what @Elin said !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = ifelse(mpg > 20, 8, cyl))
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont want transmute but `mutate`.

Your example can be written like this:

```
mtcars2 <-  mtcars %>%
   filter(mpg>20) %>%
   select(cyl) %>% 
   filter(mpg>20) %>% 
   mutate(cyl=8)
```

However, there are flaws in it, as you are filtering on `mpg` after selecting only `cyl`. Moreover, you are filtering twice the same condition, but I'd assume it is only a vision of your "multiple filter and select operations".

A working example would be:

```
mtcars2 <-  mtcars %>%
   filter(mpg>20) %>%
   mutate(cyl=8)
```

Comment: @snoram You are absolutely right, but this is because the given example is flawed in the first place (filtering on `mpg` after selecting only `cyl`). Please consider this answer as educational only. I'll add a note.

Comment: Sorry, the actual issue is, that I would want to alter the mtcars data frame and not create a new object.

Comment: @Krisselack Then remove the `2` of `mtcars2` from my answer. But you shouldn't do so if you really talk about the `mtcars` dataframe and it is not juste an example of your custom dataframe.